# How to extract a json value in Jmeter based on value of another

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter , I am trying to extract value from a json. 
Here is the json response i received :

```
    {
    Definition: {
        key: 1124,
        Id: 1743,
        srcID: "3427",
        pcKey: -1,
        userName: "abraizada",
        cName: "JMeter2016-11-27-1480283993838",
        Type: "SUBJECT",
        cohortTool: "Web app",
        cCount: 74,
        extractionStatus: "Completed",
        dateCreated: "2017-05-09T18:35:35Z"
    },
    datasource: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Claims-OMOP",
        subjectCount: 116352
    },
    project: {
        id: 747,
        name: "Jmeter Project"
    }
},
{
    cohortDefinition: {
        key: 1123,
        Id: 1742,
        srcID: "3447",
        pcKey: -1,
        userName: "IE_USER",
        cName: "JMeter2016-11-15-1479204865900",
        Type: "SUBJECT",
        cohortTool: "Web app",
        cCount: 74,
        extractionStatus: "",
        dateCreated: "2017-05-09T18:35:35Z"
    },
    datasource: {
        id: 2,
        name: "External",
        sCount: 116352
    },
    project: {
        id: 747,
        name: "Jmeter Project"
    }
},
```

From above response , I would like to extract value 'key' if   srcID=3447.
I tried  doing this
    $..cohortKey[?(@.srcCohortId = 3447)].cohortKey

But not getting result.  Could anyone help me in extracting "key" value based on condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to do this with the JSON Path expressions like below:

```
$..[?(@.srcID==3447)].key
```

where:

- `..` - is recursive descent, it help to find everywhere in the json data
- `[]` - an array, means the filter will apply and find inside an array
- `?( )` - applies a filter/condition (script) expression.
- `@` - current object
- `@.srcID==3447` - the currect object which has child `srcID` with value `3447`
- `.key` - get the key of the object which satisfies the above conditions

I make an example, and config the JSON Extractor like above

[image]

And the result

[image]

---

For more usage about JSON Extractor, please refer:

- [JSON Extractor in JMeter](https://jmetervn.com/2016/09/17/json-path-postprocessor-in-jmeter/)
- [JMeter basic](https://jmetervn.com/2017/01/28/list-of-all-posts/)

Comment: Thanks  Tom Tran. I was able to this. Now I tried to parameter it.  What should I do , if I want make 3447 as a variable ?  Step 1 : Using regular expression I am extracting an ID lets call it as CID , and Now I want to pass it to Step 2 ie Json extractor  to get key based on CID. Here is my code     $..[?(@.srcId == ${__evalVar(${cid})}].cohortKey.  But I am getting error Error processing JSON content in cohortkey JSON Extractor, message:Could not parse token starting at position 3. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *

Comment: It's the same expression as above. I assume you will extract the srcID and store it into the variable called SRC_ID, then your JSON Path expression will be: `$..[?(@.srcID==${SRC_ID})].key`

Comment: Tom , able to solve it. 
$..[?(@.srcId == ‘${cid}‘)].cohortKey . Thanks for the link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the expression which will extract the value.

```
`$..[?(@.srcID=3447)].key`
```

Reference:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter